# How do I select all the dealers that did not have an order?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join two tables and only select the dealers that did not have their promo code used on any order.

How can I do this?

I'm trying this below, but it's not working right.  In the example I want to get just Bob, since his `promo_code` hasn't been used in any orders.

```
SELECT d.`name`
FROM z_dealer d
LEFT OUTER JOIN z_order o ON (d.promo_code = o.promo_code)
AND o.promo_code IS NULL
```

Here are my tables...

```
mysql> select * from z_dealer;
+----+------+------------+
| id | name | promo_code |
+----+------+------------+
| 1  | John | holiday    |
| 2  | Suzy | special    |
| 3  | Bob  | laborday   |
+----+------+------------+

mysql> Select * from z_order;
+----+-------+------------+
| id | total | promo_code |
+----+-------+------------+
| 1  | 10    | holiday    |
| 2  | 20    | special    |
| 3  | 15    | holiday    |
| 4  | 45    | special    |
+----+-------+------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried `INNER JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT d.`name` FROM z_dealer d LEFT JOIN z_order o ON (d.promo_code = o.promo_code) WHERE o.promo_code IS NULL
```

[image: SQL JOINS]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `INNER JOIN`? or You can try `IN` like this :

```
SELECT d.name
FROM z_dealer d
WHERE d.promo_code not in( SELECT promo_code FROM z_order)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why it's not working in your example code.  I've created the same tables locally and when I run the script you provided I get the single 'Bob' answer.

```
SELECT d.name
FROM z_dealer d
LEFT OUTER JOIN z_order o ON (d.promo_code = o.promo_code)
AND o.promo_code IS NULL
```

What results are you seeing exactly?

Comment: When I run it, I get John, Suzy, and Bob

Comment: What about when you run @RubahMalam's script above?  That should yield only "Bob" as well.  If you are getting all three in your answer, then you need to check your orders table to make sure it is indeed set up as you describe above.

Comment: Well, that leaves me a bit confused.  Both should have the same results.

As an aside, are you sure the answer you chose is the one you meant to choose?  I would think that @RubahMalam's answer is a better choice since it seems to have worked for you.

Comment: The reason I didn't choose RubahMalam's answer (even though it worked) is because his used a subquery.  @rubenrp81 used a simple join.

Comment: Sure.  Just seems that @rubenrp81 gave you the same answer as your example... which I agree was already correct.

Glad you were able to get everything to work.